# "Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }}

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

App Is crashing when clicking an image with an error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.android.imageuploader/com.example.android.imageuploader.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Main Activity:-

```
package com.example.android.imageuploader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import static android.R.attr.cacheColorHint;
import static android.R.attr.data;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_click);
        clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE);                            //starting camera intent
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Upload In Progress...");
            progressDialog.show();
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child("Pictures").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Successful!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Unsuccessful!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```

LOGCAT

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.android.imageuploader, PID: 2801
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.android.imageuploader/com.example.android.imageuploader.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3406)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.example.android.imageuploader.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:56)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3359)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3406) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

read logcat. NullPointException in onActivityResult method.
com.example.android.imageuploader.MainActivity.**onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:56)** at

Comment: Your answere didnt help a bit..please explain

Comment: i guess, 'data' object is null.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still wondering , I had this problem and in my case this happened because the intent was no longer returning The Uri of the image instead it returns the image bitmap as an extra, so you can try to retrieve the bitmap from the "OnActivityResults" intent("data") extra and create a file from this bitmap and use it to upload to firebase, why the intent really did so I am not sure I was using file provider and then removed it , so I thinks it is something in this stage that changed the behavior of the intent.